# Documenting state machines - from states or transitions?

Tags: computer-science, fsm

I'm documenting a state machine. No UML. Plain text.

Is there any praxis around documenting from a state- vs a transition perspective?

#### S1: opened

Allowed transitions: close, jammed

#### S2: closed

Allowed transition: open, jammed

#### S3: jammed

Allowed transitions: none.

### vs

### T: open

Allowed states: closed

### T: close

Allowed states: opened

### T: jammed

Allowed states: opened, closed

regards,

Comment: Table with state on one axis, "events" that cause transitions on the other, cell for state/event names the next state?

Comment: Yes, it corresponds to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_finite-state_machine#State_Table but it's a bit counter-intuitive from an action-based perspective.